# Flutter Dart how to get data from Sqflite and wait for it then display it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to get List of 'tasks' from the database

I am getting the data via the `onOpen()` of the `openDatabase` function, and I store the data in a List in another dart file named `constants.dart` that contains `List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>? tasks;`,

And this is how I get the data

```
import '../shared/components/constants.dart';

onOpen: (database) {
  getFromDatabase(database).then((value) {
    tasks = value;
    print(tasks);
  });
}
```

And the tasks printed successfully

Now I need to access the data from another file `current_tasks.dart`, so I imported the tasks from its file to build `ListView` from `tasks`

```
import '../../shared/components/constants.dart';
```

and in the `itemCount` I tried to call `tasks.length`

```
itemCount: tasks.length
```

But I got error

```
The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'
```

I tried to but `!` after `tasks`

```
itemCount: tasks!.length
```

But I got this error

```
Null check operator used on a null value
```

I think that I must wait for the database to get the data then build the ListView but I don't know how

Comment: Hi can you share the code of `ListView.builder`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably what are you saying,  getFromDatabase is a future method, so it takes some time get the values and when you call tasks!.lenght the tasks is not ready and is null. you can do something like that

```
onOpen: (database) async{
  getFromDatabase(database).then((value) {
    tasks = value;
    print(tasks);
  });
}
```

when you use the onOpen method, type await onOnpen. For more information look about future methods. I hope this can help you out.